# How to print a bill from browser on epson thermal printer

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, printing, thermal-printer

I want to print a html bill ( Generated through data coming from rest api ) on epson tharmal printer.

I have tried normal print command using Ctrl + P and showing correct print preview but its printing empty page.

Can anyone tell me how can i achieve this thing.

I have also tried this code http://orbatao.com/ePOS-Print_SDK_151113E/JavaScript/ePOS-Print_Sample_SDK_V5.0.1E/canvas/canvas-print-text.html

But I don't know how to connect thermal printer with tcp/ip port. Initially Printer is connected with LPT1 port.

Comment: Check the page settings. If page settings don't match it might just print blank page. Checkout EPSON Support page: http://www.epson.com/cgi-bin/Store/support/supDetail.jsp?infoType=FAQ&oid=201984&foid=210533

Comment: I got the solution with http://qz.io they heve given some system application software which we have to install in our computer and call their socket script to print from thermal printer.